# SignatureType class

Tags: c#, xml, sign

I have to sign some XMLs. I have found a lot of examples of how to sign an XML using the "SignedXml" class, and add the XmlElement of the signature at the end of the XML that needs to be signed.

Like this:

```
SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

// Add the key to the SignedXml document.
signedXml.SigningKey = certificado.PrivateKey;

// Create a reference to be signed.
Reference reference = new Reference();
reference.Uri = "";

// Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());

// Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
signedXml.AddReference(reference);

KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificado));
signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

// Compute the signature.
signedXml.ComputeSignature();

// Get the XML representation of the signature and save
// it to an XmlElement object.
XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

// Append the element to the XML document.
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
```

But using this example the signature is done after the serialization of my object.. I would like to use the class "SignatureType" that was created inside of the objects (they were created by using xsds files along the xmldsig-core-schema.xsd, that contains the class "SignatureType" ), and then just send serializable the object.

Somenthing like this:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();

var signature = new SignatureType();
signature.SignedInfo = new SignedInfoType();
signature.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = new CanonicalizationMethodType();
signature.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod.Algorithm = "Algorithm";
signature.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = new SignatureMethodType();
signature.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod.Algorithm = "Algorithm";
signature.SignedInfo.Reference = new[] { new ReferenceType { DigestMethod = new DigestMethodType { Algorithm = "Algorithm" }, DigestValue = new byte[] { 4, 5, 6, 8 } } };
signature.SignatureValue = new SignatureValueType();

myObject.Signature = signature;

using (Stream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Create))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, myObject);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
}
```

But I really don't now how to use the "SignatureType" correctly. Does someone know where can I find examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for enveloped, enveloping and detached XML signatures, their differences and what is useful for your purpose.

We use enveloped signatures (HMACSHA256), as in your first example above, for years. This is a good solution for us, because it is flexible. The signature is appended as a child of the root, so the `XmlSerializer` of the .NET class is not influenced and the signature can be checked in an additional step. Or can be ignored.

Comment: This is true, enveloped signature implementation can be used for others xml's that I eventually need to sign. Tks for the answer.